# Calling a class method with scoped coroutine in Kotlin/Native on Linux throws exception

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-native

I have this code on Linux, using Kotlin/Native:

```
//
// This class could be in common module or in 'linuxMain' source set,
// either way doesn't work
//
class MyClass : CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
  fun execute() = launch {
    delay(1000)
    println("finished")
  }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
  val clazz = MyClass()
  clazz.execute()
}
```

This throws an exception:

```
kotlin.IllegalStateException: There is no event loop. 
  Use runBlocking { ... } to start one.
```

What do I do wrong?

- If `MyClass` is external and I can't modify it, how to solve this?
- For some reason if I run the code from the `main()` function in Android Activity (which doesn't even inherit or use any `CouroutineScope`), it runs perfectly well. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainScope()` creates a scope that uses `Dispatchers.Main` dispatcher. This dispatcher launches coroutines in UI thread (in Android, Swing or JavaFX applications). From its [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-main.html):

> Access to this property may throw an IllegalStateException if no main dispatchers are present in the classpath.
>
> ...
>
> In order to work with the Main dispatcher, the following artifact
>   should be added to the project runtime dependencies:
>
> ```
> kotlinx-coroutines-android — for Android Main thread dispatcher
> kotlinx-coroutines-javafx — for JavaFx Application thread dispatcher
> kotlinx-coroutines-swing — for Swing EDT dispatcher
> ```

That's why it works on Android and doesn't work on Linux. There are no UI libraries in your `linuxMain` classpath, so `Dispatchers.Main` throws an exception *(although docs say that it should instead be equivalent to `Dispatchers.Default` for Kotlin/Native, I don't really know why it doesn't work in your case, please ensure that you build your project correctly)*.

There is a way to fix it, but it requires changing `MyClass` and involves some workarounds:

```
fun getMyScope() = try {
    runBlocking {
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {}
    }
    MainScope()
} catch(ex: IllegalStateException) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
}

class MyClass : CoroutineScope by getMyScope() {
  fun execute() = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    delay(1000)
    println("finished")
  }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
  val clazz = MyClass()
  clazz.execute().join()
}
```

This code will use main dispatcher for platforms where you need to work in UI thread, and will use default dispatcher on other platforms. If you don't need to use the main dispatcher at all, this code can be simplified:

```
class MyClass : CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {
  fun execute() = launch {
    delay(1000)
    println("finished")
  }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
  val clazz = MyClass()
  clazz.execute().join()
}
```

Comment: Actually it turns out that `MainScope` on Linux delegates to `Dispatchers.Default` and even if I explicitly specify this dispatcher, exception is still thrown in my (and yours) example **unless** I call `.join()`. But if `execute()` is void there's no way I can do this. I wonder why. Again, this works on Android without calling`.join()`